# JRE 7 Applet does not connect with Tomcat when SSLv3 is Disabled

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, applet, sslv3

Not sure if anyone else ran into this issue or if someone has an answer for me.

My JRE 7 Applet breaks when connecting to a Tomcat server running on JRE 7 when SSLv3 is Disabled in server.xml.

TLS is Enabled and all the Cipher Suites are carefully selected to make sure the UI loads up. Verified on all browsers and the webpages work just fine. TLS is is forced on the browser and even from the Java Control Panel (on the client side) but when the Applet UI is loaded, applet fails with an error related to **SSL Handshake failure**.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Any ideas on what might be happening here?

Thanks.
aSun

Comment: 'TLS is enabled and all cipher suites are carefully selected' *how?* Code please.

Comment: In the server.xml after several combinations, even with the following 2 ciphers the Browser brings up the UI and am able to use it except for the Java Applet. 

sslProtocol="TLS" 
ciphers="TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"